# How to delete an image from photo library using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` in my application to pick up the image. I need to delete this image synchronously from iOS PhotoLibrary after picking it up in my application.

```
- (BOOL)createAndInsertNewElementFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
AlbumElement *newElement;

if ([dict[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]
     isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie])
{
    NSURL *mediaUrl = dict[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    newElement = [AlbumElement createElementWithMediaUrl:mediaUrl
                                                 inAlbum:_album.name];

}
else if ([dict[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]
          isEqualToString:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage])
{
    UIImage *image = [dict[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] copy];
    newElement = [AlbumElement createElementWithImage:image
                                              inAlbum:_album.name];
}

if (newElement != nil)
{
    [_album.elements insertObject:newElement atIndex:0];

    UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[newElement iconFullPath]];
    [AlbumElement writeImageToFileWithImage:icon
                                 atFullPath:_album.albumIconPath];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Element was NOT added!");
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [dict objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] ;  

PHPhotoLibrary *library = [PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary];
 [library performChanges:^{
// Here assetsURLs is array of url's you want to delete 
    PHFetchResult *assetsToBeDeleted = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:url] options:nil];
    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assetsToBeDeleted];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
 {
     // Check error and success here
}];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks it works fine for me. But it showing message when deleting photo . How to modify that message.

Comment: It is confirmation message , By default from apple in this approach you can't hide this. I will share if i find another approach . For more info check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922796/disable-confirmation-on-delete-request-in-phphotolibrary

Comment: Is it possible to select multiple Images from photo library.

Comment: No from default , But you can impalement it via 3rd party libraries as https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController

Comment: if you use camera to capture image , this will not save in photo library .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{


NSURL *imgURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]performChanges:^{


    PHAsset *imageAssetTodelete = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:imgURL options:nil];

    [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:imageAssetTodelete];


} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"err description : %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
    if (success) {

        NSLog(@"image deleted successfully");
    }


}];

 }
```

And don't forget to `@import Photos;` in your class.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score -1):

I use the same code like #MOHAMMAD ISHAQ but in my case that not work, the picture are not deleted, I have no any error.
Any help or suggestion please ?

```
PHAsset *asset = nil;
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
if (fetchResult != nil && fetchResult.count > 0) {
    // get last photo from Photos
    asset = [fetchResult lastObject];
}

if (asset) {
    
    PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *editOptions = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc] init];

    [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOptions completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

        if (contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL) {
            //do something with contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL
            
            NSLog(@"¨PATH %@",contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL);
            
            NSMutableArray *persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
            [persons addObject:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL];
            
            NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:persons];
            
            PHPhotoLibrary *library = [PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary];
          
            [library performChanges:^{
               
    
                PHFetchResult *assetsToBeDeleted = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:myArray options:nil];
       
                [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:assetsToBeDeleted];
            } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
             {
                 //do something here
                NSLog(@"DELETE IAMGE");
            }];
        }

    }];
```

Thank