# how to delete a photo album after a given time frame?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm creating an app and I want it to be configurable to delete photo albums after a given time frame.  For example, by default, the program should delete a photo album created within its context after 30 days.

How would you go about doing this?  For example, can the app contain some type of background job that runs every hour to check if it's time to delete a photo album?  It looks like someone asked a similar question in the past:

[Disable confirmation on delete request in PHPhotoLibrary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922796/disable-confirmation-on-delete-request-in-phphotolibrary)

However, I basically just need to host photos within the context of my custom app.  Is it possible to create a PHPhotoAlbum within the context of a particular app where that particular app is the owner of that particular album and has full rights to that album so the app can delete its own photo albums without prompting the user?

Comment: Like the commentary on the linked question states - you don't have full API control over Photos and its library, and this goes doubly so for an individual album. This might be better suited for having your app make its own internal photo library.

Comment: Thanks sschale.  Can you provide a url that might help me get started in the direction you mentioned?  I googled swift internal photo library but wasn't able to find any results to give me traction with the approach you mentioned

Comment: So I don't know exactly what you're trying to do with it, but I've had a decent experience using `MWPhotoBrowser` to display images I capture using the default `UIImagePickerController` - those 2 terms should get you started. Search github or cocoapods for photo gallery